# what is the difference between $P(A \cup B)$ and $P(A \cap B)$?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Given the example $P(A)= 0.1$ and $P(B)=0.20$ how would I find these two things ?

Comment: Recall that $P(A\cup B)$ is the probability that the event is in $A$ or $B.$ $P(A\cap B)$ is the probability that the event is in $A$ and $B.$

Answer (score 3):

You don't have enough information.  It could be that $P(A \cap B)=0$ if they never happen together.  It could be that $P(A \cap B)=0.1$ if every time $A$ happens so does $B$.  Do you understand the definitions of $\cup$ and $\cap$?

Answer (score 0):

In probability, an event can be thought of as a set of outcomes. Thus $A$ and $B$ are sets which represent events. In this context, $A\cap B$ is the set of outcomes that the events have in common. For example, if $A=\{$child gets bike, child does not get bike, child steals bike$\}$, and $B=\{$child steals bike$\}$, then $A\cap B=\{$child steals bike$\}$.

In contrast, $A\cup B$ is the set of outcomes of *either* of the events. Using the same example as above, $A\cup B=\{$child gets bike, child does not get bike, child steals bike$\}$.

If $A$ and $B$ have nothing in common, $A\cap B=\emptyset$, where $\emptyset=\{\}$ is the [Empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set).

In general, when learning probability theory, it is an essential to be comfortable with elementary set theory, as probability theory is heavily reliant on set theory. [Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Set_Theory/Sets) you will be able to learn the basics of set theory. Good luck! :)